# Calling a class method by ajax does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a button in an html page that allows you to start updating the data to display in a table.
This update is launched at the click event via an ajax call. The ajax call works fine except that the data has not been refreshed.
By doing a little test on my code, I realized that if I launch the method of my class directly reloading the page, the data is refreshingly refreshed.
That's what I do:

```
<?php 
if(PermissionManager::isSuperAdmin()){

    require_once('controllers/RiTableController.php');

    if(isset($_POST['ri']) && $_POST['ri'] == "refresh"){
        RiTableController::refreshRIData();
    }

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/ri_table.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            rendertable(<?php echo json_encode(RiTableController::getDataTableRi())?>);

        });

        function launch_ri() {
            $(".loading").css("display","block");

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                //url:'ri_table_view.php',
                data:"ri=refresh", 
                success: function(data){
                    $(".loading").css("display","none");
                    alert('successful');
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        };

 </script>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <h1>IR list</h1>
     <h4 type="text" value="">IR tracking list of builds</h4>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="display: flex;align-items: center;margin-bottom:30px">
    <div class="col-md-2">
     <button type="button" id="launch_ri" name="launch_ri" onClick="launch_ri();" align="right" class="btn btn-default">Refresh List</button>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <table style="font-size:12px" width="100%" id="table_RI" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover"></table>
 </div>
</div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Here is the method called

```
public static function refreshRIData(){

        set_time_limit(180);

        // Insert data in db from Plan
        RITable::insertRiFromTPaln();

        $data_Ri = RITable::gtRiForRefresh();

        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($data_Ri) ; $i++) { 

            // set RI ref
            $RI = $data_Ri[$i]['ri_ref_ri'];

            // get all transactions impacted by this RI
            $transactions_impacted_result = RITable::getTransactionImpacted($RI);

            // prepare variable to insert in db
            $transactions_impacted = json_encode($transactions_impacted_result);

            // get first transaction impacted
            $transaction_result = RITable::getTransaction($RI);

            $transaction = json_encode(array('pod_id' => $transaction_result['pod_id'], 'pod_name' => $transaction_result['pod_name']));

            // get info of Ri from webservice
            $info_ri = json_decode(WebServiceController::RefreshRI($RI));
            //echo '<pre>'; print_r($info_ri); echo '</pre>';
            $owner = $info_ri->response->owner;

            // format date
            $create_date = new DateTime($info_ri->response->creation_date);
            $create_date = $create_date->format('Y-m-d H:m:i');

            $target_date = new DateTime($info_ri->response->target_correction_date);
            $target_date = $target_date->format('Y-m-d H:m:i');

            // create Pno cache for users
            if (isset($owner)) {
                $cache_to_renew = !Login::cacheToKeep($owner);
            }

            if($cache_to_renew){
                self::reLoadPno($owner);
            }

            // get brand of user in cache pno files
            $brand = RcaviewController::getBrand($info_ri->response->owner);

            // call method to insert data in db
            RITable::updateRI($RI, $info_ri->response->title ,$info_ri->response->current, $issue, $transaction, $info_ri->response->required_for_program, $info_ri->response->owner, $brand, $target_date, $create_date, $transactions_impacted);
        }
        set_time_limit(30);
        return true;
    }

    private static function reLoadPno($owner){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>fetchPno('".$owner."');</script>";
    }
```

I do not understand, why via the ajax the call to method does not work whereas if I call without ajax, it works.
What I want is that I can start the php process via ajax.
Do you have an idea of the problem?

Comment: "method does not work" is a bad description of your problem.  What is the error? Do you see the Ajax request in network panel, is there an error in the console? Did you add debug lines to see if things are being called?

Comment: `data:"ri=refresh"` most likely doesn't send what you want. Have you checked what goes in `$_POST` when you send that data? You should probably be passing `data:{ ri: refresh }`

Comment: Please read [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question. Thanks

Comment: You have to debug your code and tell us which kind of problem you have..

Comment: May be unrelated but there appears to be a typo here: `// Insert data in db from Plan
        RITable::insertRiFromTPaln();` You have "Paln" Should that be Plan?

Comment: The private function reLoadPno () in the class, launches another javascript method in which I put some debugging points.
When I start the process without the ajax call, I have in my console the logs of the debug points that appear.
On the other hand, when I start the nominal threading process as desired by clicking on the button and with the ajax call, in my console I have the log of the ajax call appear and nothing else.
There are no errors, it's as if the ajax call did not start the refreshRIData () function of the class.

Comment: is it possible that the problem comes from the fact that the Post of Ajax is in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

As with I understand you are wrong when you execute location.reload() after successfully received ajax data. This command reload the document and this is like restarting your page like it was before ajax call.

You have to parse data received by ajax call and display them.

Comment: Without the location.reload () , it's the same problem

Comment: Try a console.log(data) in your success callback function. You then will see the data provided by ajax call. Then you must parse and insert those data in the DOM of your page.

Comment: Data returns to me the html code of the page and not the return of the method called